# How to skip the first argument in a script

Tags: shell, shell-script

Linux Pocket Guide has a nice example on how to go over all the arguments in a script

```
for arg in $@
do
   echo "I found the argument $arg"
done
```

I am writing a script in which all the arguments will be text files, and I will concatenate all those text files and print them to stdout, however I should exclude the contents of the first argument. My first approach would be something like this

```
for arg in $@
do
   cat "$arg"

done
```

However, that will include the first argument, and as I mentioned, I want to print all except the first one.

Comment: As a side note, `"$@"` should *always* be quoted. Another side note, you can get the same functionality without the `for` loop: `cat "$@"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `shift` command like this:

```
shift
for arg in "$@"
do
    cat "$arg"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [shift](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_26) builtin to discard one or more positional parameters, but you should check the number of parameters first:

```
if [ "$#" > 1 ]; then
  # Save first parameter value for using later
  arg1=$1
  shift
fi
```

Calling `shift` without any argument meaning `shift 1`.

Looping through all positional arguments:

```
for arg do
  : do something with "$arg"
done
```

In your case, you don't need the loop at all, since when `cat` can work with multiple files:

```
cat -- "$@"
```

Here's a test for calling `shift` when there's no positional arguments:

```
$ for shell in /bin/*sh /opt/schily/bin/[jbo]sh; do
  printf '[%s]\n' "$shell"
  "$shell" -c 'shift'
done
```

Output:

```
[/bin/ash]
/bin/ash: 1: shift: can't shift that many
[/bin/bash]
[/bin/csh]
shift: No more words.
[/bin/dash]
/bin/dash: 1: shift: can't shift that many
[/bin/ksh]
/bin/ksh: shift: (null): bad number
[/bin/lksh]
/bin/lksh: shift: nothing to shift
[/bin/mksh]
/bin/mksh: shift: nothing to shift
[/bin/pdksh]
/bin/pdksh: shift: nothing to shift
[/bin/posh]
/bin/posh: shift: nothing to shift
[/bin/sh]
/bin/sh: 1: shift: can't shift that many
[/bin/tcsh]
shift: No more words.
[/bin/zsh]
zsh:shift:1: shift count must be <= $#
[/opt/schily/bin/bsh]
shift: cannot shift.
[/opt/schily/bin/jsh]
/opt/schily/bin/jsh: cannot shift
[/opt/schily/bin/osh]
/opt/schily/bin/osh: cannot shift
```

Well, `bash` is silent with no positional arguments. Calling with placeholder in `$0`:

```
"$shell" -c 'shift' _
```

made `csh` variants and schily `bsh` to be silent, too. In case of error, `zsh`, `csh` variants and schily `bsh` won't quit the non-interactive script after reporting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `shift` command to shift the args, discarding the first one. Here is an example:

```
arg1=$1
shift
for arg in "$@"; do
  cat "$arg"
done
```

Comment: It's better to check for number of positional parameters before calling `shift`, many shell will [report an error](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/230463/38906) and [quit in non-interactive shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_26_14)

Answer (score 1):

You can use array slicing `${@:2}` :

```
$ foo () { echo "The args are ${@:2}" ;}
$ foo spam egg bar
The args are egg bar
```

Comment: Note: this is not available in all shells.